# Is z-index not a dominant?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to say is that **WHY** is `z-index` ignored when in this situation?

```css
#IAmGreater{
position:fixed;
z-index: 999!important;
background-color: green;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
#parent{
background-color: blue;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
position: fixed;
margin: 50px;
}
#IAmDown{
position: absolute;
z-index: 0;
background-color:red;
height:100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<span id="IAmGreater"></span>
</div>
<div id="IAmDown">
</div>
```

`#IAmGreater` can only be on top of `#IAmDown` if I set the `IAmDown` to `z-index: -1` but in this case the `parent` div will also be on top of `IAmDown` and I don't want that.
All I want is that the Green box be on top of the Red box and the Red box is on top of the blue one.

Is there any solution to this **aside** from moving the Green box outside of it's parent, or **EDIT** the HTML?

I'm down with using JavaScript (not really on JQuery) in manipulating this but i don't know how to. Help?

Comment: The parent element creates its own stacking context. The `z-index` is not a global thing.

Comment: You should make them different divs

Comment: Change the `position` of  `#IAmGreater` to absolute while you need it to display over its parent div.

Comment: Damn it. So is there any way to get the desired output without altering the HTML data?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the dreaded stacking index problems:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context
Once you create an element with positioning: fixed, you're creating a new stacking context. You can't shuffle elements between stacking contexts.

You need to change your markup, unfortunately.

```
<div id="newParent">
 <div id="oldParent"></div>
 <span id="IAmGreater"></span>
</div>
 <div id="IAmDown">
</div>
```

Comment: _Is there any solution to this aside from moving the Green box outside of it's parent, or EDIT the HTML?_

Answer (score 0):

This works. Made a change in `html`

```css
#IAmGreater{
position:fixed;
z-index: 1000;
background-color: green;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
#parent{
background-color: blue;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
position: fixed;
z-index: -1;
margin: 50px;
}
#IAmDown{
position: absolute;
background-color:red;
height:100px;
width: 100px;
z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
<span id="IAmGreater"></span>
<div id="IAmDown">
</div>
```

Comment: _Is there any solution to this aside from moving the Green box outside of it's parent, or EDIT the HTML?_

Answer (score 0):

Its parent (`#parent`) doesn't have a z-index, that's why. If you add one which is greater than the one of `#IAmDown`, it changes as expected:

```css
#IAmGreater{
position:fixed;
z-index: 999!important;
background-color: green;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
#parent{
background-color: blue;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
position: fixed;
margin: 50px;
z-index:1;
}
#IAmDown{
position: absolute;
z-index: 0;
background-color:red;
height:100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<span id="IAmGreater"></span>
</div>
<div id="IAmDown">
</div>
```

Comment: _All I want is that the Green box be on top of the Red box and the Red box is on top of the blue one._

Comment: That won't work with the current HTML structure - you can't put an external element between a parent and its child.

Comment: so, it's basically impossible even with JavaScript?

Comment: I posted a second answer, whcih does what you want, but has a changed HTML structure. I doubt that it would even be possible with Javascript on the original HTML, since the only way to get that result is to change the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a second answer that contains a solution as you requested in the comment to my first answer. All elements have fixed position, and the green one is moved out of the red one:

```css
#IAmGreater{
position:fixed;
z-index: 999!important;
background-color: green;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
#parent{
background-color: blue;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
position: fixed;
margin: 50px;
}
#IAmDown{
position: fixed;
z-index: 0;
background-color:red;
height:100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
</div>
<span id="IAmGreater"></span>
<div id="IAmDown">
</div>
```

Comment: Then i guess it really is impossible. :/

Comment: Yea it is. You are wrapping the `span` in a `parent` and want to pu the `span` ontop it `parent`. Sounds impossible for now at least